# Is there a way to monitor all the http requests coming to .net core application hosted in IIS

Tags: .net-core, iis-7, asp.net-core-webapi, coreclr

I've implemented a httpmodule to interrupt all the http requests to my asp.net application. But it is not working for .net core applications.

If I'm not wrong we can implement middleware to interrupt requests in .net core applications. But I believe it requires changes in startup class and redeploy the application.

So, now trying to monitor all the http requests coming to .net core application hosted in IIS with out touching the application code like Httpmodule. Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use some tools to capture all request like
[network monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) and 
[fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

You can also check [IIS logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/configure-logging-in-iis) which store every incoming request information like IP address, date, time etc.

there is another tool which is performance monitor that provides a high-level view of performance counters, updated live, with time series graphs, histograms, and reports.